# rename file or move file if it is comma delimited in Linux bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, cut

I am new to Linux bash. what i am trying to do is, in a specific directory i have so many files. Some are comma delimited others are pipe delimited. I want bash script to move the comma delimited files to a different folder or rename the files. All files are .csv. I was experimenting using cut & awk but it didn't work out for me. Any help is highly appreciated. for example

Input

```
File1.csv -> a|b|c|d

File2.csv -> c,d,e,f

File3.csv -> G|H|I|J
```

Output

```
File2.csv will be renamed to File2Comma.csv or move to a different directory because it is comma delimited.
```

Comment: What have you **tried**?

Comment: Show sample input and expected output. A comma-delimited file might contain pipe symbols and vice-versa so how can you tell whether any given file is comma or pipe-delimited? e.g. is `a,b|c,d|e` comma or pipe delimited?

Comment: Ed, i have put in some example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $(find . -type f)
do
    grep ',' $i && mv $i YourDir  # you can use "grep ',' $i && echo $i" test
done
```

Comment: It would be good to explain what each line / subshell is doing.

Comment: And the caveats and dangers involved in each of the lines.